# How do I create a numbered list of words?

Tags: lists, keywords

I would like to list the keywords for my thesis on the format:

1. First Keyword, 2. Second Keyword, 3. Third Keyword, ...

But not had to type the numeration manually, so the command would be like:

```
\mykeywodslist{First Keyword,  Second Keyword, Third Keyword}
```

Then calling the command:

```
\printmykeywordlist
```

Would print them like:

```
1. First Keyword, 2. Second Keyword, 3. Third Keyword
```

Comment: Why not simply write `1. First Keyword, 2. Second Keyword, 3. Third Keyword`?

Comment: Because you have to keep track of counting them, and when you add or remove some item, you have to manually edit all the others indexes affected.

Comment: Considering you supposedly will have an average of 5 *keywords*, that's a waste of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `enumitem` package with `inline` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate*}
    \item First Keyword
    \item Second Keyword
    \item Third Keyword
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

See documentation for changing the style of labels.

Comment: Thanks! Could it be attributed to a command line like `\printkeywords` and the `inline` option be local to my enumeration, so not all enumerations are inlined?

Comment: @user That's what the `*` does for you.

Comment: Forgot why, but unless one knows what one is doing it's better to load enumitem with the unboxed option, also, i.e. `\usepackage[inline,unboxed]{enumitem}`